# Xamarin.Forms - Page PopAsync pass parameters

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am looking for solution to pass parameters from the current page to a previous page and way how to check that the page was popped from another page in Xamarin.Forms.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass information from one page to another you can either use events or MessagingCenter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center.

As a personal suggestion, I would try events first, if you cant achieve whatever you want with plain events, then you should give a look to MessagingCenter.

But as a TL;DR, the MessagingCenter allows components/viewmodels to communicate without knowing anything about each other.